# Notification for my website's app when I have new campaigns

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

I have an online shopping website and I want to send notifications to the users(people who downloaded the app of the site) when the website has new campaigns, or a campaign is about to expire but I'm confused what to do.

p.s.: I created my app by using webview button so I'm not sure I can add another button as notification button.

Comment: Check out Firebase Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible without API ..you have to make API which generate push notification when you generate new campaigns